# Condition - should unlock before await?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Could you tell me if I should release lock before await on condition?

```
try {
    lock.lock();
    while (isNotEmpty()) {
        condition.await();
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Or

```
try {
    lock.lock();
    while (isNotEmpty()) {
        lock.unlock();
        condition.await();
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Have you read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)?

Comment: `acquire(); try { use(); } finally { release(); }`. If your acquire (`lock`) fails then you'll release the resource you never held. In this case, you may unlock an enclosing lock of the [reentrant] lock.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, you do not need to explicitly release the lock before calling `await`, `await` will release it automatically. From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28%29):

> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the
>   current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes[...]

And:

> The current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this `Condition` when this method is called.

Answer (score 4):

You can only `await()` on a `Condition` when you have lock()ed the associated `Lock`

Why don't you have a condition for isEmpty to make your conditions clearer.

See the example in the Javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

e.g.

```
 lock.lock();
 try {
   while (count > 0)
     isEmpty.await();
   // do something when empty.
 } finally {
   lock.unlock();
 }
```

Comment: *"You cannot await on a lock, you don't have locked."* Presumably `lock` is the lock associated with `condition`.

Answer (score 1):

wait and notify must be called from with in the synchronized block, so the **same rule applies for await and signal. Though await releases automatically, but if you do it should be between lock() and unlock()**

```
lock.lock()          // start of synchronized block

condition.await()

lock.unlock()        // end of synchronized block
```